# Modifications to a php form

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin

Beginner in php here.
I have the following form script:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])) {

$db_name = "xx";
$server = "localhost";
$DBuser = "xxx";
$DBpass = "xxxx";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$file = "Imagini_lume/" . $email . ".jpg";

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Adresa de e-mail este incompleta!";
} else {
    $name = trim($name);
    if ($name != '') {
        $temp_file = trim($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        if ($temp_file != '') {
            // here
            mysql_connect($server, $DBuser, $DBpass) or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
            // check for existing
            //$result = mysql_query("select email from Emails where email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
            $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            if ($data == null) {
                mysql_query("insert into Emails (Email,Full_Name,Image) values('$email','$name','$file');") or die(mysql_error());

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
                    //sucess
                } else {
                    echo "Eroare incarcare imagine!";
                }
                // email sending
                sendEmail("xx@gmail.com", getContent($name, $email, $file));
                echo "Sucessfull!";
            //} else {
                //echo "Adresa de e-mail este folosita de cineva.";

            }
        } else {
            echo "Trebuie sa selectati desenul dvs.!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Introduceti numele complet!";
    }
}} else {
    echo "Va rugam sa completati spatiile de mai sus!";
}
```

Note: `if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])) {` and `} else {
echo "Va rugam sa completati spatiile de mai sus!";}`
are on different lines than stated above. I only added that way so I can include all script inside the "code sample".

The questions are:

1. If the user uploads several files using the same name and e-mail address, the files will overwrite and I would like to differentiate the files (e.g. "name@email.com1.jpg","name@email.com2.jpg" and on).
   I already found the script but being a beginner, I don't know where to insert the following code (another note- I don't know if it's the full code or some script is missing):

   ```
   while(file_exists($name . $extension)) {
       $name .= '1';
   }
   ```
2. I would like to "oblige" the user to type it's full name. Due to design reasons I have only one "Full name" text box and I would like to force the user to type at least 2 words (first and last name) - basically a word minimum nr, not characters nr. Again, I have found a code, but still, I don't know how to apply it to my code, where to insert it:

   ```
   if ($("#et_newpost_content").text().split(/\s+/).length < 250) {
       alert('Message must be at least 250 words.')
   }
   ```

Please advise.

Comment: newfurniturey - Thanks for the Editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's quite simple. The first script to increment the image name counter is quite simple to implement:

1)

```
$db_name = "xx";
$server = "localhost";
$DBuser = "xxx";
$DBpass = "xxxx";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
// Now checking the name existence
// Defining the initial state: the format is: my@email.com + counter + extension
// i.e. my@mail.com1.jpg
$ext = ".jpg";
$count = 1;
$base_file_name = "Imagini_lume/" . $mail;
// while already exists a file name like that, increment count
while (file_exists($base_file_name.$count.$ext))
    $count++;
// finally define the official name of the file!
$file = $base_file_name.$count.$ext;
```

2) the code you wrote is javascript (jquery), not php... If you want to check the parameter server side you can use filter_var:

```
if (filter_var($name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*/"))) === FALSE)
    die("Error: You should enter your complete name. i.e. John Black");
```

(take a look to regular expression chapter on the php guide)

Finally, please don't use that code in a real web application. As it's written, it's not safe on SQL injection attacks:

[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Moreover you are not checking the correctness of each user input parameter. Take your time to make some experience ;)

Comment: Sorry for wrongly stating about issue nr.2.Correct me if I'm worng, the new code will start like this?   [link](http://acemarket.net/DeAgostini.ro/Craciun2013/send_version1.txt)                                           Another question raised in my mind is, will your script work even if the ext is png or gif?

Comment: To use the original file extension you should do like this: $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']));

Complete code:
http://pastie.org/8525746

Comment: After trying the code the files saved on ftp look like "name1extension"(E.G. 1PNG) and they don't have any extension.(type - file)

Comment: Sorry but still the same result

Comment: Hey,no problem. Now the image results like "1.Png". I was wondering if it could be possible to keep its previous script ("namemail.ext") and add a counter at the end if the pics are similar (namemail2.ext, namemail3.ext)?

Comment: http://pastie.org/8525892 to customize it, try to edit the $base_file_name variable

Comment: Worked! Many thanks!! Too bad I cannot vote your answer due my rep., but great job! One thing though, about the "filter_var", the script you inserted has conditions regarding the usage of "only" letters and capital letters at the beginning of the names, but my need is only for a minimum one space(->minimum 2 words). How can I modify your script(" filter_var") and could please use your latest script[link](http://pastie.org/8525892) to show me where to insert the updated "filter_var"?

Comment: You can accept the answer with the "V" below the voting tab (near my answer), I think... About the limitation of one space, try this ;) http://pastie.org/8526088